# Bootstrap Popover Trouble

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
 Logged in as <a href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Username <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

I've tried various things to fix, but unfortunately, nothing seems to be helping; the popover does not work when clicked. Would there be any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this video tutorial : [bootstrap tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YJUFaZMS8Q)
this would help. you should match the `id` of popover to `href` of the link you want to trigger the popover. for example your popover `id` is `popover` then your `href` should be `#popover`

Comment: Thank you, but after trying, the fix still didn't seem to work.

Comment: java-script is a case sensitive language. try checking the code again. i assure you there is a little small problem with your code like missing semicolon ...